# How to disable textbox depending on option selected in listbox in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, textbox

I want to **disable textbox** depending on **option selected** in listbox in **rails 3**

I have the code for **select and text box**

```
 <%= f.select "type_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@types, "type_id","name")%>
 <%= f.text_field :zonetype  %>
```

- It displays the list of types
- I want to do is **if I select no type** the text box following the select **must be disabled**

How to do this please help me....

Comment: Use jQuery http://jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks denis I wil try plz send some links about it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use jQuery or similar to find the change event of your select box, something like:

```
$('selector').on('change', function(){ do-stuff });
```

The "selector" would be a jQuery selector that finds your select list (probably by ID).

The "do-stuff" would be setting the text field to disabled, this would look something like:

```
$('selector').prop("disabled", true);
```

This time the "selector" would be a jQuery selector that finds your text box (probably by ID).